# Why is the <b> and <i> not working?

Tags: html, css, css-reset

I have this site http://www.korsholm-jagtrejser.dk/

In the text

> Korsholm Jagtrejser kan tilbyde jagtrejser til et bredt udvalg af
>   jagtlande

Korsholm has `<b>` around and jagtrejser has `<i>` around, but it does not shown as bold/italic. I'm using meyerweb reset css, which have a `<b>` and `<i>`.

My chrome inspector does not say anything about that it should not be bold.

Can somebody pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Post code? Anything to do with CSS reset may have an affect on your meta tags

Comment: use a normalize instead of a reset.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the [reset.css](http://www.korsholm-jagtrejser.dk/fileadmin/templates/reset.css) stylesheet has `font: inherit;` which is overriding the browser's CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font: inherit; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline;}
```

Comment: Why on Earth would a CSS reset decide to do this I cannot fathom.

Comment: Which part of "reset" don't you understand?  The purpose of a reset.css is to reset everything to do nothing so you can add your own styling.

Comment: Frankly, now that IE7 is mostly dead, CSS resets seem largely redundant anyhow - browsers are mostly compatible.

Comment: Good catch, @AlienWebguy - explains your 27.4k reputation :)

Comment: incidentally, this kind of vertical align resetting is pretty... unexpected too.

Comment: So Eric Meyers reset css file is outdated?

Comment: Outdated is probably the wrong word. It's not like this used to work and now it doesn't. Just find another one that suits your needs. There are a bazillion.

Answer (score 6):

The reset stylesheet has `font: inherit;` against a selector that matches lots of different things including `b` and `i`. [`font`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop) includes `font-weight` and `font-style` so it sets those to the values of the parent element.

Answer (score 2):

You have 'font' set to `inherit` for the `b` tag in reset.css in line 19.  Either remove the b tag or add a new selector for it to change the font-weight.

Comment: This actually the only thing worked, remove it from the reset.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I tend to use very minimal resets if any for reasons like that.

Answer (score 1):

When you use CSS Reset, it resets all the styles. Now you need to use a CSS UnReset. I recommend using [**Vanilla CSS Un-Reset**](http://noscope.com/vanilla-css).

The full code is given here:

```
/**
 * Start Vanilla CSS 1.0.2 
 */ 
body {
    font: 9pt/1.5em sans-serif;
}
pre, code, tt {
    font: 1em/1.5em 'Andale Mono', 'Lucida Console', monospace;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
em, i, dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}
dfn {
    font-weight:bold;
}
p, code, pre, kbd {
    margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
}
blockquote {
    margin:0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
}
cite {
    font-style: italic;
}
li ul, li ol {
    margin:0 1.5em;
}
ul, ol {
    margin:0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:disc;
}
ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
}
ol ol {
    list-style: upper-alpha;
}
ol ol ol {
    list-style: lower-roman;
}
ol ol ol ol {
    list-style: lower-alpha;
}
dl {
    margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
}
dl dt {
    font-weight:bold;
}
dd {
    margin-left:1.5em;
}
table {
    margin-bottom:1.4em;
    width:100%;
}
th {
    font-weight:bold;
}
th, td, caption {
    padding:4px 10px 4px 5px;
}
tfoot {
    font-style:italic;
}
sup, sub {
    line-height:0;
}
abbr, acronym {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
address {
    margin:0 0 1.5em;
    font-style:italic;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
pre {
    margin:1.5em 0;
    white-space:pre;
}
img.centered, .aligncenter, div.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
img.alignright {
    display: inline;
}
img.alignleft {
    display: inline;
}
.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
* + html .clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
* html .group {
    height: 1%;
}
* + html .group {
    display: inline-block;
}
.group:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/**
* End Vanilla CSS
*/
```

And the nice thing is, you can use whatever is required and what you don't.

Comment: I know just added
`b, strong {font-weight:bold !important;}`
`i, em {font-style:italic !important;}`
But this just doesnt not work (tried with important just to see if it changed anything) - This is AFTER the reset